# Which is better between changing Nameservers and changing DNS "A" Records?

Tags: dns, nameserver

I have my hosting on Godaddy and domain on another server. So I was thinking which would be a better option to point the domain to Godaddy hosting

1. Change the name server to that of godaddy.
2. Change the DNS "A" Record on the site where I have bought the domain.

thanks...

/neer

www.technimi.com

Comment: This is not a question that belongs on stackoverflow.com, serverfault.com is better suited for this.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you have a static IP, you should just point the domain to your web host's nameservers. Even if you've purchased a unique IP, the IP can change if your web host decides to move you to a different server (e.g. a temporary relocation while the server is being fixed or upgraded) or restructure their network.

Very rarely would you ever want to manually create a DNS record instead of pointing to the proper nameservers.

Answer (score 2):

That's a viable option, especially if you want to keep your mail (MX record) with the domain registrar.  If you do that, however, be sure to move the CNAME record over as well; A and CNAME really should be kept together as a rule.

Answer (score 2):

Changing the Name Servers is better.

While it isn't common, the IP address for a server can change, if they do and you've set an A record, your site will go down if you don't update.  On the other hand, if you set Name Servers and the IP is "embedded" into a Name Servers themselves, you won't have that same downtime if the IP changes.